# что мешает apache2 разбирать URL?

Tags: php, apache

Изучаю основы MVC фреймворков по этому [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTESlsYTUns) , остановился на одном эксперименте(собственно [вот код](https://github.com/ReijiAkkerman/haruproject.space) на котором я остановился).

Если я запускаю встроенный php сервер ссылка `http://localhost:8080/contact` моим кодом обрабатывается без ошибок, но когда я выключаю php сервер и запускаю `apache2` то код перестает работать.

Вопрос - почему? и как я могу реализовать подобную обработку URL в `apache2`?

Следующие настройки `.htaccess` не работают:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: Что значит "перестаёт работать"? А под апачем какой адрес открываешь? и как настроен vhost? и какая ОС?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский под "перестает работать" я имею ввиду отсутствие маршрутизации, а именно при открытии ссылки через `http://localhost/contact` я получаю стандартную страницу "404 Not Found".

Comment: Ну это смотря как ты сайт настроил и через что.....просто установить апач и включить его - не достаточно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ОС Ubuntu 22.04, <VirtualHost *.80>ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/haruproject.space
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined</VirtualHost>
Конфигурация hosts ---- 127.0.0.1           localhost

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а что нужно для нормальной работы сайта со стороны `apache`

Comment: https://losst.pro/nastrojka-virtualnyh-hostov-apache  ........ https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-18-04-ru

Comment: @АлексейШиманский к сожалению эти ссылки я прошерстил еще когда пытался поднять сам сайт на `apache`, сейчас же пытаюсь разобраться с обработкой запросов URL

Comment: @АлексейШиманский P.S. домашняя страница localhost работает не обрабатываюся с помощью apache ссылки со всем тем что идет после слеша типа `http://localhost/(user, contact, id etc.)` исключения прямые действующие ссылки

Comment: ....Ладно как скажешь.............. ЗЫ, если у тебя в index php заходит при всяких `localhost/user`, то проблема в итоге в маршрутизации, которая прописана в php, а не в апаче

Comment: @АлексейШиманский В пример вот ссылка https://github.com/ReijiAkkerman/haruproject.space, фактически файла `haruproject.space` не существует но сама ссылка как-то обрабатывается сервером чтобы выдать пользователю нужную "фактически существующую страницу" - как я могу сделать такую же обработку?? Просто две недели я пытаюсь это сделать и все предыдущие вопросы возникали в попытках решить именно эту проблему. Пожалуйста помогите понять этот механизм

Comment: у вас файл `.htaccess` вообще работает? в апаче должна быть включена директива возможности переопределять настройки хоста через этот файл.

Comment: Прицип абсолютно такой же: всё направляется в один файл а он маршрутизирует..... как именно - зависит от ресурса....например в vk  если вписан алиас, то вначале через свои механизмы анализируется это алиас группы, сообщества или пользователя и перекидывает на соответствующую страницу......так что если в index прилетает при любых `/sdfuysdf`, то вся проблема в маршрутизации

Comment: @ArchDemon AccessFileName .htaccess ------ да вроде все есть

Comment: это не та директива. Напишите в файле `.htaccess` полный бред, сохраните и зайдите на сайт. Если он откроется, то файл не работает

Comment: @ArchDemon Спасибо Вам большое))) .htaccess и правда не подключался из-за `AllowOverride None` - поменял `None` на `All` в `<Directory /var/www/>` - и все заработало))))